# in mac, new tab functionality is not working

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

When i click on copy link it means url is copied , then open new tab and paste the copied url in new tab using selenium webdriver.
Below code is working in windows not in mac.
when i used this code in mac system, some java software icon is coming in taskbar. Attached screenshot for your reference.[Java software icon in right corner and application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCUV8.png)[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbxgN.png)

My Code:

```
 String element=Util.OR_VF_MY_ACCOUNT_PAGE.getProperty("myAccountPageCopyUrlLinkInWishList");
            $(element).click();

    winHandleBefore= getDriver().getWindowHandle();
            Set<String> handles =  getDriver().getWindowHandles();
            //getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            for(String windowHandle  : handles)
            {
                if(!windowHandle.equals(winHandleBefore))
                {
                    getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);
                }
            }
            Util.pause(4);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            Util.pause(4);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            Util.pause(4);
```

Comment: Not control, by mistake i have added. In mac we have to use command.Please resolve this issue

Comment: Does this mean this is not the correct code? If so please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41298918/edit) your question to prevent confusion.

Comment: java control panel icon is coming. can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because on a Mac/Unix OS there is no "Control" key. Try to use the "Command" key instead on Mac/unix systems.

Here is a [post](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/) on how to check which system is operating so you can change from "Ctrl" to "Command" automatically

**Edit**

With javascript you are able to open new tabs/windows depending on the browser implementation. I have no idea if a new window will be accesible through the same WebDriver instance (and I can't test it out atm).
But basically this snippit should work on most Drivers.

```
// driver is your WebDriver instance
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "var win = window.open('http://www.example.com/', '_blank');" +
    "if (win) {" +
    "    //Browser has allowed it to be opened" +
    "    win.focus();" +
    "} else {" +
    "    //Browser has blocked it" +
    "    alert('new tab/window couldn't be opened');" +
    "}");
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("This driver does not support JavaScript!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have added command key on mac. But issue is i need to open new tab without clicking any link, just i have to copy the url and paste in new tab using code on mac.For that i was using Robot code but when i run this code,some java software icon was coming on task bar.

Comment: Can anyone give rply for this question as i am waiting for this. Please tell me

Comment: @ksyam Unfortunatly there is no official way to open new tabs in selenium. Most try to send the ('ctrl'/'command') + 't' to the 'body' element of the page (or just like you with a robot). With both ways it is not 100% fail proof. One way to open new tabs/window (depending on the browser type) is using javascript. Ill edit my answer with an example script you can run in your browser.